# Terminology: matrix diagonalizable as a bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, diagonalization

If a matrix $P$ is such $P^{-1}MP$ is diagonal, we say that *$P$ diagonalizes $M$* (implicitly, as the matrix of an endomorphism).

Now, if $P^\top M P$ is diagonal, is it correct to say that *$P$ diagonalizes $M$ as (the matrix of) a bilinear form*? It seems correct to me but I have never read this, so I am wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sure that is perfectly normal terminology ([for example here](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~jkamnitz/courses/mat247_2014/bilinearforms2.pdf), [or here](http://batty.mullikin.org/quadratic.pdf), [or here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/S13/notes/MAT_217_Lecture_19.pdf) [or here](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.782/LectureNotes9.pdf). Frankly I'm a little surprised you never ran across this usage.)

The thing in common between the two processes is that they take two matrices that are expressing something as a matrix (resp. linear transformation, bilinear form) and connecting it with the new matrix after a change of basis (using, resp. similarity, cogredience). Whichever equivalence relation you are using, it makes perfect sense to call the classes represented by diagonal matrices "diagonalizable."

Comment: I ran accross the diagonalization of a quadratic form or bilinear form many times, but never that "a matrix is diagonalizable as the matrix of a bilinear form". Every time I read matrix + diagonalization it was using a conjugation transform $P^{-1}MP$. From a quick look, it seems the link you provided never mention the diagonalization of the _matrix_, but of the form.

Comment: @anderstood But there is *only* diagonalization of the matrix. Strictly speaking, diagonalization of "the form" doesn't make sense. Similarity and cogredience are the relations that tell us which *matrices* represent the single form. You can relax the language and talk about the form being diagonalized yes, but all it means is that you've found a diagonal matrix representing it.

Comment: Strange that search engines return nothing (except this question) for "diagonalizable as a bilinear form" or "diagonalizable by cogredience". But I understand the answer, TY.

Answer (score 1):

The natural operation for changing variables in a quadratic form amounts to the expression $P^T H P,$ where $H$ is the Hessian matrix of second partials of the form, and $P$ is nonsingular. In matrix theory, $H$ and $P^T H P $ are called **congruent.** There is an evident equivalence relation.

Sometimes the Hessian, or half the Hessian, is called the Gram matrix of the form.

When $\det P = 1,$ then $P^T H P$ and $H$ define quadratic forms that are called equivalent. In dimension two, care is taken, but in higher dimension $\det P = \pm 1$ is generally used.

If all entries of $H$ are integers and all entries of $P$ are integers, the revised form is called equivalent; if all entries of $P$ are rational, $\det P = \pm 1,$ then the forms of $H$ and $P^T HP$ are in the same genus, although there is a condition called "without essential denominator." This definition is due to Siegel.

Maybe an example. Let $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2.$ The Gram matrix $G$ is just the identity. Then $$f(3x+y, -5x + y) = 34 x^2 -4xy + 2 y^2.$$
Well,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & -5 \\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 1 \\
-5 & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
34 & -2 \\
-2 & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$